# Rotate SVG path using CSS

Tags: css, svg

I have this SVG:

```css
* {
  background: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<svg class="decor" height="100%" preserveaspectratio="none" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0 0 L100 100 L0 100" stroke-width="0"></path>
</svg>
```

How to rotate it by 180 degree?!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gjdjp642/)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Just use the element type selector and add the `transform: rotate(180deg)` property to it like in the below snippet.

```css
* {
  background: #e1e1e1;
}
svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<svg class="decor" height="100%" preserveaspectratio="none" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0 0 L100 100 L0 100" stroke-width="0"></path>
</svg>
```

---

Or, if you want to rotate only the `path` and not the `svg` itself, then include a `transform-origin` like in the below snippet:

```css
* {
  background: #e1e1e1;
}
path {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg class="decor" height="100%" preserveaspectratio="none" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0 0 L100 100 L0 100" stroke-width="0"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Great answer! Just a note on support for IE 6-8: https://caniuse.com/#search=transform-origin

Comment: Caveat emptor: be cautious if adding transitions or animations you have to keep in mind that you rotated the element and that "down" might just be "up"

Answer (score 16):

**Inline** you would do it like this:

- **x-axis flip** : transform="scale(-1 1)"
- **y-axis flip** : transform="scale(1 -1)"

eg. in your example:

```
<svg class="decor" transform="scale(-1 1)" height="100%" preserveaspectratio="none" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0 0 L100 100 L0 100" stroke-width="0"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Adding transform="scale(-1 -1)" worked for me instead of transform="scale(-1 1)"
I think there's a typo in your example

Answer (score 4):

You can also rotate the path of the SVG directly via a **transform** in the  itself.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="rotate(90 50 50)" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <path d="M0 0 L100 100 L0 100" stroke-width="0"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Error: <svg> attribute transform: Trailing garbage, "rotate(180, originX, originY…".

Comment: Image not showed yet

Comment: transform="rotate(90 0 0)" is working

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the style attribute to rotate 180 degrees like so:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" data-node-id="a0cef7b2-6c8c-458d-8b52-0c8b80c65008"
     data-comp-instance-id="8450d308-bfd8-4e2e-b3b9-a875c5a54700"
     data-type="icon" style="transform: rotate(180deg)">
    <path d="M342 214l468 298-468 298v-596z" data-node-id="a3145c10-0a28-4d2c-8b7b-8331bc1905c7" data-comp-instance-id="8450d308-bfd8-4e2e-b3b9-a875c5a54700" data-type="path" class=""></path>
</svg>
```

This will display a triangle pointing left.